Should I add my affiliation as an Intern in a paper?
I am a MS student in Physics, and doing a full-time internship in research lab of a company. Recently, I worked on a paper with some of my collaborators -- unrelated to the project that I'm doing with people in this company. Should/Can I also add this companies name as affiliation?
I found several somewhat related question but they doesn't directly answer this.

Who are your 'collaborators' - if the company than use the company as the affiliation (although I'm presuming the full-time internship is paid?).

@JonCuster The collaborators in this work are not from the company. Yes, the internship is paid.

OK, where are those collaborators from, and who funded the work? When did you perform the work relative to your internship?

@JonCuster The collaborators are from different universities, and funded by various grants. The work started before I joined the internship but extended up to now (I joined the internship more than a month ago).

Since you are doing a paid internship, you are an employee of the company. If it has a research lab, it probably has a policy on publications and might have a policy on outside work. Ask your supervisor at the company about this situation.
Where I work, the relevant policies are:

Any paper I publish using my workplace as my affiliation must be approved
for publication by my boss and uploaded to our manuscript management
system before I submit it.
Any outside work that I do -- even in my own time -- must be approved by my boss in advance. This is particularly important for research work.

The upshot is that if I want to work on and publish a paper while working here, my boss needs to approve it one way or the other (either as outside work without my corporate affiliation or as a publication with my corporate affiliation).
